# IE11 is reporting a syntax error for [...a]

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, internet-explorer-11

In chrome and firefox, this is a non issue but IE11 is giving me a syntax error 1002 at this line:

```
let aCopy = [...a];
```

But I don't understand what the solution is. Babel gives me this giant output:

```
function _toConsumableArray(arr) { return _arrayWithoutHoles(arr) || _iterableToArray(arr) || _nonIterableSpread(); }

function _nonIterableSpread() { throw new TypeError("Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance"); }

function _iterableToArray(iter) { if (Symbol.iterator in Object(iter) || Object.prototype.toString.call(iter) === "[object Arguments]") return Array.from(iter); }

function _arrayWithoutHoles(arr) { if (Array.isArray(arr)) { for (var i = 0, arr2 = new Array(arr.length); i < arr.length; i++) { arr2[i] = arr[i]; } return arr2; } }

var aCopy = _toConsumableArray(a);
```

Can anyone refer me to what this actually all means?

Comment: What is your `a`?

Comment: it's just a text string. It can be anything.

Comment: @Sweepster: Are you running the Babel output in IE11, or the original source?

Comment: Array spread is an ES6 feature. IE 11 doesn't support like 99.95% of ES6 features. Show your `.babelrc`.

Comment: @connexo it's right there in my question where I put "Babel gives me this giant output:"

Comment: No `.babelrc`there. Are you using `@babel/preset-env`?

Comment: Are you saying that the original line doesn't work in IE, or that the Babel version doesn't work in IE?. IE doesn't support `Symbol`, so you would need a polyfill for that.

Comment: @JLRishe My question is asking for resources to help understand what the babel version means.

Comment: @Sweepster Which part of it are you having trouble understanding? The function names are pretty self-explanatory. Have you tried reading their code?

Comment: @Sweepster: But the Babel version doesn’t matter if you’re running the pre-Babel version, which is a likely cause of the problem if you’re seeing a syntax error…

Answer (score -2):

IE 11 does not support spread syntax for iterable objects (with sparse arrays, in array literals). It required a js compiler to transform [...array] to es5 codes (https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/4922). Please refer to https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-spread_syntax_for_iterable_objects